# added solution to svn and now I don't see it

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

We have just recently got our SVN server installed.  My developers have added the solution to the repository from within Visual Studio, but they must have done it wrong because I can't find it in the repository anywhere :(

Additionally, I uploaded a java project from eclipse and the folder shows up in the proper trunk location but there are no files that I can see in the folder.

any suggestions, tips or tricks for repository management?

**edit:**

Some additional information. When I remote desktop to the server and go to the VisualSVN Server (Local) view there is an address of `https://VMSVN.metrocourt.nm.us/svn/` when I click on that and sign in I get an IE window that shows the directory structure of the repository.  The main folders are Applications and Shared_Libraries, I click on Applications and see C# Applications, Java Applications (which are folders I created in the repository) and another folder DocketDisplay (this is the project the developers did the 'Add solution to repository command on from within Visual Studio).  However, when I look at the Repository tree within the VisualSVN Server navigator I don't see the DocketDisplay application, just the folders I created within the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, I found that I needed to also perform  a 'Commit'. That's a menu pick in the VisualSVN menu in Visual Studio.  After doing that, the files appear in the respository.